# trying to remove an item from List

Tags: list, coldfusion, lucee

I have a code working good, but i am trying to do an enhancement

https://trycf.com/gist/5fdbccd52121856991e6fe3f82307d34/lucee5?theme=monokai

in the above, i am trying if the deleted item in list is `IN`, it should also delete the other item starting with `I` letter

The code is looping for the list elements and doing a match to detect and delete the element

**Source**

```
<cfscript>
    i = 'AS,AK,SK,SB,IN,IP';
    Y = 'IN';
local.X = [];
        listEach(I, function(value, index) {
            if (!listFindNoCase(Y, value)) {
                arrayAppend(X, value);
            }
        });
dump(x);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: You mean you wanna delete `IP` and `IN` if `IN` is found in your list?

Comment: yes, and same is with other cases, if i delete SK, it should delete its relevant starting from S and same is with AB

Comment: You are welcome to post links, but please post the code HERE as well, so the question remains helpful to others too (not just you), long after the link breaks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by checking before if the list contains your element using `listFindNoCase`, then using `listFilter` to filter the items you do not want in your new list, something like this:

```
<cfscript>
originalList = 'AS,AK,SK,SB,IN,IP';
needle = 'IN,AS';
newList = originalList;
listEach(needle, function(needle) {
    if (listFindNoCase(newList, needle)) {
        newList = listFilter(newList, function(value) {
            return lcase(left(value, 1)) != lcase(left(needle, 1));
        });
    }
});
dump(newList);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: That will not work, if i had two values in needle like 'IN,AS'

Comment: How many different values can the "needle" list contain, and what are those values? What is the expected result for each of those values?

Comment: Changed the code so it considers a list of arguments to search for in the original list.